# Can't install pandas using pip

Tags: bash, pandas, unix, macros, pip

I have tried to install pandas through pip but it gives the following error:

```
    Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas'
```

I am using  macOS Sierra 10.12.5. I downloaded pip using `sudo easy_install pip`.

Any guidance on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way (may be not the simpler) is to install anaconda.
https://www.continuum.io/downloads#macos

I don't believe you need only pandas ))

Anaconda contains pandas and a lot of packages that you'll definately need in your ML practice.

Comment: Pandas was the first thing I needed :P. Without that nothing will work anyway. Thank for the idea. I was considering that. But I thought it would be better if I could do it on Python itself

Comment: I can probably get it if I do `sudo pip install pandas` but from what I've read, using sudo with pip is not recommended